# How to out-box a Nazi?

Tags: indiana-jones-and-the-last-crusade

In Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade (graphical adventure) there are numerous opportunities to fight Nazi soldiers.  You can complete the game without a single fight, but if you choose to throw punches at the Nazi's you will learn pretty quick that:

1. Your health does not restore between fights
2. You cannot spam punches
3. Later enemies are a lot stronger (a few are very difficult to overcome, such as the ticket collector)

The fighting system lets you move back and forward.  You can either block or throw to the head, upper body and lower body.

Through numerous attempts I cannot come up with a decent strategy to out-boxing a Nazi.  Some of the easier/early fights are generous in that you can spam moderately but later on you got to move and/or block accordingly.

I could not come up with a successful strategy after the first 3 Nazi's I came across.  It was as if I was blocking randomly in the hope I would catch a punch with my hands rather than my head/body.  I could not see anything that helped decide where to block and when to block.

Answer (score 4):

Softability links a great resource about fighting in this game, one that I've used to great success. However, the specific resource you're looking for can be found [here](https://indyguide.mixnmojo.com/fighting.html):

> **Step One - Attacking**
> The first thing you need to understand is the fighting system itself. It's rather weird and confusing, but it's really important that you fully comprehend it to be any good.
> The right hand column on the numeric pad is LOW, MID and HIGH attack (that's keys [3],[6] and [9] respectively) right? It's all well and good trying to punch HIGH when the guards block LOW, but you've also got to keep and eye on the RED BAR on the lower right hand corner of the screen. This is Indy's Punch Power and it goes down every time you use it. It recharges quickly, but it means that if you miss the first couple of times, that when you do eventually connect it'll only do a tiny bit of damage. You've got to time it so that you punch when it's full or it isn't worth punching at all.

> **Step Two - Basic Defence** The next step is to start using those defence keys! ([7],[4],[1])You may start off trying to use the middle row to BLOCK the enemies attacks. Sod that. Just use the RETREAT keys, they are MUCH easier and it'll improve you chances of winning by at least 50%. The basic pattern is to ATTACK and then quickly RETREAT. This way when you punch the Nazi your punch energy will be full because you'll be hitting him sporadically. He'll then take a step towards you, quickly ATTACK him and RETREAT again. It doesn't matter if he blocks a few because the ones that connect will do a lot of damage. Keep doing this as long as you can.

> You will come to a point however when you can retreat no more! You'll hit the left edge of the screen and you'll just have to block as best you can until you win. By this time however, if you did the above right you'll still have full energy while the Nazi only has half! Using these tactics GREATLY increases your chances of winning! The energy you lose to the rest of the fight will be mostly the Yellow recoverable kind that goes back up after a fight, not bad eh?

> **Step Three - Advanced Defence** The problem with Step Two is that eventually your energy will get worn down, and although you can replenish it halfway through the game at Castle Brunwald, it isn't ideal. This is where the centre row ([8],[5],[2]) comes in.

> Don't get me wrong, you CAN complete the game semi-easily using Step Two, but if you want to be able to take on the Security Guy in Brunwald or the Ticket Taker on the Zeppelin you'll need to be proficient in blocking. I won't lie to you, it's bastard hard! The first thing you need to do is start to look carefully at what the guards are doing. The graphics in Indy Lc aren't the greatest so it's not immediately obvious if the baddies fists are HIGH, LOW or whatever. You need to be able to tell before you can block it!

> The next step is pretty straight forward and obvious, so I'll keep it short. Wait for the baddie to punch you and then attack him. You can retreat after this if you want or just try your hand at blocking again. It's up to you what you do, there isn't any short-cut around it. It's just pure skill and a LOT of practice. Good luck